# How to parse attribute and value of a tag in html file at same time with Nokogori?

Tags: html, ruby, shell

Say I have a html file called `ex.html` like following:

```
<ul>
    <li data-value="datav1">val1</li>
    <li data-value="datav2">val2</li>
    <li data-value="datav3">val3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to extract attribute `data-value` and the text value line by line and output the result as below:

> datav1:val1
>
> datav2:val2
>
> datav3:val3

However I'm new to **Nokogori**, all I know is the code below,which can only extract the attribute `data-value`, and I don't know how to extract attribute and text value in the same loop.

```
require 'nokogiri'
page_temp = Nokogiri::HTML(open("ex.html"))
page_temp.xpath('//li/@data-value').each do |node|
    puts node
end
```

I'd really appreciate that if anyone can teach me how to make it work through **Nokogori**, and it would be better if there is any other solution could simply by using shell script.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for @Rajarshi Das and @Arun Kumar, your answers partly solved my problem. Now the problem is that `node.text` are some Chinese characters. And they are unrecognizable when I print them out in terminal.
I tried to print out the `page_temp` when after I executed `page_temp = Nokogiri::HTML(open("ex.html"))` and I find that all Chinese characters are like `&#128;`. So I guess I read the `ex.html` file wrong in ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
page_temp.xpath('//li').each do |node|
  puts "#{node['data-value']}:#{node.text}"
end
```

The code is self-explanatory but let me explain. You're looping over all the `li` elements and printing the value of `data-value` attribute along with the text contained in the `li` element.

Comment: Thanks, I think your way is pretty easy. However the `node.text` are some Chinese characters, so the messages printed are unrecognisable when I simply follow your way. Should I set the encoding? And how can I find whether is the encoding settings issue from ruby interpreter or from iTerm2?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way....

```
 page_temp.xpath('//li').each do |node|
  puts "#{node.attributes['data-value'].value}:#{node.children.first.content}"
end
```

and output get

```
   datav1:val1
   datav2:val2
   datav3:val3
```

By nokogiri you can do it step by step like first step

```
 page_temp.xpath('//li').each do |node|
```

you can get the output of what it give by just taking one item

```
 page_temp.xpath('//li').first
 #=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1827ae0 name="li" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1827aa4 name="data-value" value="datav1">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x182781c "val1">]>
```

now you need datav1:val1

so datav1 is in attributes

```
page_temp.xpath('//li').first.attributes
   => {"data-value"=>#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1827aa4 name="data-value" value="datav1">}
```

so to get it you can do `page_temp.xpath('//li').first.attributes["data-value"].value`

page_temp.xpath('//li').first.attributes["data-value"].value
   #=>datav1

now for val1

there is also a `children` attribute of that nokogiri instance and it contains the element text/content

so

```
page_temp.xpath('//li').first.children
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x182781c "val1">]
page_temp.xpath('//li').first.children.first.content
=> val1
```

now get two desire output element in the loop use these as `page_temp.xpath('//li').first` replace by `node` and show it in desire format of string.

so it would be

```
"#{node.attributes['data-value'].value}:#{node.children.first.content}"
```

Comment: Thanks, you answer is really helpful. Could you please help me to figure out  the issue I commented on @Arun Kumar 's answer?

Comment: yes you need to encode those `force_encoding('utf-8')`

Comment: like this `puts "#{node['data-value']}:#{node.text}".force_encoding("UTF-8")`? it doesn't work though.

Comment: `"#{node.attributes['data-value'].value}.force_encoing('utf-8'):#{node.children.first.content}.force_encoing('utf-8')"`

Answer (score 0):

this work

```
<style>.Middle {
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 1350px;
background-color: blue;
border: 0px solid black;
} 
</style>
<div align="center" class="Middle">
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
  <option>Change data</option>
  <option value="http://www.mrdicky.cf/">data1</option>
  <option value="http://www.mrdicky.cf/">data2</option>
  <option value="http://www.mrdicky.cf/">data3</option>
</select>
```